# Ajax call cannot find PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, .htaccess

I am doing a ajax call , but its giving a error saying 404 file not found.

```
        $.ajax({ 
            type      : 'POST',
            url       : 'app/lib/functions.php',
            data      : data,
            success   : function(data) {

            }
        });
```

My project struc is this

[image]

I am doing a ajax call from main.js (in public fodler) to functions.php (in app folder).
Please help. I am tired of this.
Edited : I tried with ../ and ../../ in front of the url in ajax but it does not work. I think its something to do with app folder , as this folder is not available to client side , something like that. I dont know how to do the ajax now.
My .htaccess has this code as I am redirecting to public folder by default.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /proj_name/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /public/([^\s?]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,NE,R=302]

RewriteRule ^((?!public/).*)$ public/$1 [L,NC]
```

**EDIT** : If I remove the .htaccess , '../app/lib/functions.php' path works

Comment: Is your site being hosted by a server, or running on a local server? Or are you just loading the page in a browser as a local file without any server?

Comment: @IceMetalPunk I am using localserver

Comment: did you try with "/app/lib/function.php"?

Comment: @FélixBrunet yes

Comment: I think you need to have your php file inside your public folder. Check this answer by Quentin https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21377416/jquery-ajax-url-not-found

Answer (score 0):

maybe try it with:

```
$.ajax({ 
        type      : 'POST',
        url       : '../../app/lib/functions.php',
        data      : data,
        success   : function(data) {

        }
    });
```

or

```
$.ajax({ 
        type      : 'POST',
        url       : '../app/lib/functions.php',
        data      : data,
        success   : function(data) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't use AJAX much but I believe it should be pointing to a route, not directly to a file.  That path would be relative and never actually resolve.

Comment: so what should i do

Comment: Can you turn that directory /app/lib/functions.php into a route, so youd be accessing <baseurl>/functions and sending post data.  This way it is accessible much like an API and dynamic and can be called the same from anywhere.  it also seems like you are calling the whole file when I am assuming you may only need a single function from it.

Comment: You can use the __DIR__  variable and append to route to the file lik __DIR__ . ../.. or wherever you want to go